# What are the options on the wp.media JavaScript object in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to create a custom file uploader for frontend in wordpress. I've found this code:

```
file_frame = wp.media({
    multiple: false 
});

file_frame.open();
```

It works like a charm. But i've been searching and I havent found a full list of the attributes that can be modified in wp.media

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to open the default wp media gallery onclick of some button ,

```
     $example_images.sortable({
        items: 'li',
        cursor: 'move',
        scrollSensitivity: 40,
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        forceHelperSize: false,
        helper: 'clone',
        opacity: 0.65,
        placeholder: 'wc-metabox-sortable-placeholder',
        start: function( event, ui ) {
            ui.item.css( 'background-color', '#f6f6f6' );

        },
        stop: function( event, ui ) {
            ui.item.removeAttr( 'style' );

        },
        update: function() {
            var attachment_ids = '';

            jQuery( '#bs_example_images' ).find( 'ul li' ).css( 'cursor', 'default' ).each( function() {
            });

        }
    });
```

Thank you